# Amplitude.js и Ajax

Tags: javascript

Как работать с Amplitude.js через Ajax? Если страница загружена динамически, то инициализация не происходит.

```
Amplitude.init({
  songs: [
    {
      "name": "Risin' High (feat Raashan Ahmad)",
      "artist": "Ancient Astronauts",
      "album": "We Are to Answer",
      "url": "../songs/Ancient Astronauts - Risin' High (feat Raashan Ahmad).mp3",
      "cover_art_url": "../album-art/we-are-to-answer.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "The Gun",
      "artist": "Lorn",
      "album": "Ask The Dust",
      "url": "../songs/08 The Gun.mp3",
      "cover_art_url": "../album-art/ask-the-dust.jpg",
    },
  ],
});
```

Comment: По приведенному здесь коду не понятно как именно и в какой момент времени вы производите инициализацию.

Comment: Инициализация производится на странице, которая потом загружается через load ajax. Если открыть страницу обычным способом, то все работает, если загрузить её через Ajax, то нет

Comment: Убедитесь для начала, запускается ли вообще тот javascript код, который вы загружаете таким образом.

Comment: Проблема решена. Не знаю почему, но метод load() вырезает все script. Пришлось использовать ajax и html()